# Is there an iOS spreadsheet app that can do data filters?

Tags: ios, numbers, iwork

Google Sheets only does data filters in the browser, their mobile app does not support that feature. Is there another iOS spreadsheet app that does support such a feature? Basically, I want to be able to filter data for a column in a spreadsheet on my iPhone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft Excel is available for iOS for free.

Downloading and viewing Excel spreadsheets can be done once it is installed.

Editing (including filtering) can be done if you signed in to Microsoft's service inside the app.  You can log out immediately after having logged in, if you prefer not to be signed in.

Some features will not be available until you subscribe to Office 365.

Comment: Cool, I tried the MS Excel iPhone app, and it does support filtering. One thing that lacks though (which I didn't mention in my original question) is cloud/collaborative editing/syncing. My current solution is to use Dropbox to sync the Excel file between computer and phone, but then I can only edit in one place at a time. Unfortunately Microsoft OneDrive's excel does not support filtering. =(

Comment: Well.  That is one down, one to go then.  Maybe contact Microsoft to ask, if you can combine OneDrive with SharePoint or ask, if there is something like that in planning.

Answer (score 2):

Numbers has filters across the iOS web and Mac versions of the app.

On iOS, select a column, row or some cells then click on the button that appears in the bottom right of the screen you can filter them.

Comment: Nice work describing the way to tap and get a filter. A screen shot of this in action might really help others use this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets iOS app has added data filters now.

Screenshot from iOS app:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although correct, it may be eventually deleted if left unedited because it offers no concrete information about this new functionality, neither does it give any examples from your personal experience, nor are any informational links provided to back up your assertion.

Comment: @IconDaemon thanks for the tip, added a screenshot.