# Search on all sheets in Google Drive on iPhone

Tags: search, google-apps

In the Google Drive app, I can search all sheets for some text. But it just lists the files containing that text. If I click on a particular spreadsheet, the spreadsheet opens, but it doesn't move to the page/sub-sheet where the text was found. Inside the spreadsheet, I can search, but only on the current sheet. So it seems like I have no way of actually finding where text is when I have multi-sheet spreadsheet?

I know on Google Sheets through the Web app (using a web browser on a PC) I can search all sheets of the current spreadsheet, but I can't find the same thing on the iPhone app. I do understand that the iPhone app might not have all the functionality of the Web app, but this seems like a basic function to me.

Answer (score 0):

From the question

> but this seems like a basic function to me.

Send your feedback directly to Google. This could be done directly from the apps for iPhone. Excuse that I don't give you specific instructions about how to do this in Google Drive and Google Sheets for iPhone. I don't have one with me at this time. This is relevant because Google frecuently change the wording. Usually the path is Menu > Help then you might found an option saying something like "Help {app name} to improve", "Send your feedback", etc.

You might also send your feedback through the corresponding product community https://support.google.com/drive/community for Google Drive and https://support.google.com/docs/community for Google Docs Editors including Google Sheets.

From the question

> So it seems like I have no way of actually finding where text is when I have multi-sheet spreadsheet?

Review the **iPhone and iPad** tab in [Find files in Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375114?hl=en) and the section "Use find and replace in a spreadsheet" in the **iPhone and iPad** tab
[Search and use find and replace](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/62754?hl=en). Both links are from Google Product Help, the first from Google Drive Help, the second from Google Docs Editors Help.

Slightly related [Is there an iOS spreadsheet app that can do data filters?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/179710/274411) has an answer including a snapshot of Google Sheets app for iPhone about using filters.

This is about the Google Sheets apps for iOS. It hasn't an answers yet: [In-cell carriage returns in Google Spreadsheet iOS app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/395882/274411).

Similar recent question from the Google Docs Editor community whitout answers and locked: [search inside all sheets within workbook using "Find and replace" on iPhone](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/205719659?hl=en)

Comment: It's Menu > Help & Feedback > Send Feedback